# Swift: How to hide API URL and parameters in iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, security, url

I'm curious to know, is there any way where I can store API url and parameters safely which cannot be compiled in reverse engineering? In other words I don't want to use the base urls in the constant file. I want to save it in some other place which is more secure. Can any one let me know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is literally **no way** to keep it completely secret, You should store them as a binary. So you can either do it your self (there are a lot of tutorials about this out there) or using a semi or fully automated library and scripts like **cocoapods-keys**. Also upfuscation can help you to make it harder for attacker to decode the hardcoded string.

But remember:

> The best way to keep a secret, secret, is not to keep it at all!